# How to change the "solid" name in stl file without opening the stl file?

Tags: ascii

I have an stl file which contains two stl regions within it. But, both the region of the stl has a default name "solid ascii". I need to change the name of this. Since, the file is large, I want to change the name without opening the stl file manually. How do I do it?

Regards,
Sunag R A.

Comment: how is that related to vtk, paraview and openfoam ?

Comment: @MathieuWestphal The stl geometry files are used in OpenFoam for meshing further and work with simulations. I am in the same line. Many OpenFoam and Paraview users use stl files for their simulations. So, I added those tags..!! Thanks..!!

Comment: Could you include a minimal example and the expected result?

Comment: not related then. you may want to remove these tags.

Answer (score 0):

@s.ouchene

Here is the example.

```
solid ascii
facet normal -0.536525 -0.0166023 -0.843721
 outer loop
   vertex 7.07022 18.65 0.333244
   vertex 7.58125 19.5437 -0.00930786
   vertex 7.58125 18.65 0.00827789
 endloop
 endfacet
facet normal -0.190641 -0.254401 -0.948123
 outer loop
   vertex 7.07022 18.65 0.333244
   vertex 6.6875 18.9368 0.333244
   vertex 7.58125 19.5437 -0.00930786
 endloop
 endfacet
endsolid ascii

solid ascii
facet normal -0.40066 -0.665201 -0.630063
 outer loop
   vertex 7.07022 18.65 0.333244
   vertex 7.58125 18.65 0.00827789
   vertex 7.58125 18.3422 0.333244
 endloop
 endfacet
facet normal -0.20615 -0.543502 -0.8137
 outer loop
   vertex 7.58125 18.3422 0.333244
   vertex 8.475 18.65 -0.0987778
   vertex 8.475 18.0032 0.333244
endloop
endfacet endsolid ascii
```

In this, the solid has same name as "ascii" for two solids. I have kept the example short for only two triangles in each solid.